# Snappy sharing resources and updates

Tags: snap

I have 2 questions about snappy (which I absolutely love!) that I wanted to ask. I hope it's OK I am merging them into one thread :)

1. Sharing resources

   My first example snap build is a java server I developed. I managed to create a snap that contains the jre, my server and the service startup. Everything works fine.

   The snap file results in 106MB which is mainly java. I was wondering if there is a way to share the java installation between servers? So that my snap files become very small only containing specific code for my installation?

   In my head this would sort of look like this:

   - Snap 1: A snap that contains the Java runtime and exposes java for others to use. I believe slots are used for that, but I am not 100% sure on that.
   - Snap 2: Server A that only contains my jars and uses the java runtime of Snap 1.
   - Snap 3: Like Snap 2 but with different jars.

   I would have Snap 2 and 3 depend on Snap 1, so that if someone installs Snap 2, it would automatically install Snap 1. If Snap 1 is installed, it will skip that and simply use it?

   I am not sure if this is supported or if this is even meant to work that way?
2. Update mechanism.

   I read that snappy supports transactional updates. I read that as "if the download or installation breaks, the update fails and the previous version will run as expeceted".

   I wonder if the update is a append-update. I am having deployment environments that have limited connectivity, so it would be cool if the update worked in an rsync manner. E.g. the update starts downloading, gets to 20% and then the connectivity breaks. It retries after a while and once the connectivity is back up, it picks up where it left. 
   Is this something that is implemented/works?

Comment: Please split this into 2 questions, that way future users can browse the questions as one knowledge base, thanks!

Comment: Sorry - i was away for the weekend and now the question has gotten an update. Should I still split it?

Comment: yeah if you have time to fix up both questions to read more like knowledge articles that would be great, then we can flag up and clean all the comments and then let google do it's thing for discoverability, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Trying to answer your merged questions:

Question 1: This mecanism isn't available as of today (we may introduce one in the future, with the 3 separated snaps as you infer, but this isn't available now).
Another option you can seek if, if snap 2 and 3 are tightly coupled, you can have one snap containing the jvm, and your 2 services. Then, some configuration to choose what to start (service 1, service 2 or the two of them).

Question 2: This isn't the case nowdays, however, I encourage you to file a bug to request such a feature [as a bug on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd).

Comment: Thanks! I raised a bug/feature request: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1594297

Comment: I also split this question now and copied your answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/789260/sharing-resources-between-snappy-packages/789261#789261